# glmmTMB() returns invalid model formula in ExtractVars in R

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I'm fairly new to R and have been trying to find the solution to this on here, but none of the advice has helped my specific case. I hope I'm not missing something obvious.

I want to fit a generalized linear mixed model to get an idea which radius has the most effect on species richness in my study (250 m, 500 m etc). This is the code I used. all the variables in the formula have been correctly assigned beforehand (but the columns have the same name in the original data, just to be extra sure) and I had no issues before I got to this specific line of code:

```r
mod_cover.radii <- glmmTMB(
 species.richness ~ forest.cover.250 + 
 forest.cover.500 + 
forest.cover.750 + forest.cover.1000 + 
forest.cover.1500, 
   data=bees, family=gaussian, na.action)
```

R tells me this line of code has invalid model formula in `ExtractVars`. I've tried different ways of writing the formula (using $, leaving out spaces), but I just can't figure out what's wrong here.

For some reason, I don't run into the same issue with this:

```r
mod_complex <- glmmTMB(
 species.richness ~ forest.cover.250 + 
  forest.edge.250 + size + 
  flower.species.richness, 
  data = bees, family = gaussian)
mod_nested <- glmmTMB(
  species.richness ~ forest.cover.250 + 
  forest.edge.250, 
  data = bees, family = gaussian)
```

Comment: This error comes from deep inside C code of the base R `terms` method. What happens if you rename the variables so they don't have (as many) periods/numbers?

Comment: @PBulls thank you for the quick comment! I just tried it like this: mod_cover.radii <- glmmTMB(specrich ~ cover25 + cover50 
                           + cover75 + cover100 + cover150, 
                           data=bees, family=gaussian, na.action) and it returned the same error message.

Comment: remove the `na.action` ... (unless you name them) the arguments are passed by position and this will not make sense for the fourth parameter

Comment: @user20650 this worked! I put 'na.action = na.fail' instead, since I need to use the dredge() function next, and I did not get an error message this time. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific: here is the result of `args(glmmTMB)`:

```r
function (formula, data = NULL, family = gaussian(), ziformula = ~0, 
    dispformula = ~1, weights = NULL, offset = NULL, contrasts = NULL, 
    na.action, se = TRUE, verbose = FALSE, doFit = TRUE, control = glmmTMBControl(), 
    REML = FALSE, start = NULL, map = NULL, sparseX = NULL)
```

You can see that the next argument after `family` is `ziformula`, so the object `na.action` (which in this case is an S3 generic method) gets passed as `ziformula`.

I guess it would be possible to try to detect this kind of typo, but the general case would be complicated.